# Sheets flag duplicates when Column A and Column B exactly match another row in the column

Tags: google-sheets, duplicates, conditional-formatting

Column A - First Name
Column B - Last Name

I need sheets to flag when a duplicate appears (we have duplicate submissions for the same person submitted via a google form)

I understand how to make it so that if there's a duplicate in column A it will highlight, however first name is not enough of an identifier (e.g we often have two Joe's that are 2 different people therefore not 'duplicates')

How do I write something that says if Column A & B match exactly show me 'duplicate'?

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75055353/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results.

Answer (score 2):

Put this formula in cell `C2`:

`=arrayformula( if( countifs(A2:A, A2:A, B2:B, B2:B) > 1, "duplicate", iferror(1/0) ) )`

Alternatively, use this [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule for the range `A2:B`:

`=countifs($A$2:$A, $A2, $B$2:$B, $B2) > 1`